# What are "social, political and economic standards" for joining EU?

Tags: european-union

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine%E2%80%93European_Union_relations):

> On 2 March, however, Spanish foreign minister José Manuel Albares stated that "belonging to the EU is not a capricious process or one that can be done by a mere political decision", reminding that the candidate country "must meet certain social, political and economic standards"

What are specific "social, political and economic standards" for joining EU mentions here.

I don't see an answer for this matter in [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18321/if-turkey-can-join-eu-can-china-join-eu-too) posted earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Albares appears to be referring to the Copenhagen criteria - so called because they were set out in the [conclusions of the 1993 European Council](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/enlargement/ec/pdf/cop_en.pdf) held in Copenhagen.

> The European Council today agreed that the associated countries in Central
> and Eastern Europe that so desire shall become members of the European Union.
> Accession will take place as soon as an associated country is able to assume the
> obligations of membership by satisfying the economic and political conditions
> required.
>
> Membership requires that the candidate country has achieved stability of
> institutions guaranteeing democracy, the rule of law, human rights and respect
> for and protection of minorities, the existence of a functioning market economy
> as well as the capacity to cope with competitive pressure and market forces
> within the Union. Membership presupposes the candidate's ability to take on the
> obligations of membership including adherence to the aims of political, economic
> and monetary union.

That covers the economic and political conditions - the 'social standards' possibly refer to the ability of the European Union itself to integrate the new member state:

> The Union's capacity to absorb new members, while maintaining the momentum
> of European integration, is also an important consideration in the general interest
> of both the Union and the candidate countries.

Comment: That's the official line.  What is the reality?

Comment: "respect for and protection of minorities" This point should be problematic for Baltic states, but they were able to join EU.